# Getting weird date from NSCalendar.dateFromComponents

Tags: swift, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents, weekday

I am trying to get a date from the `component`'s `year`, `week`, and `dayOfWeek`, but I am getting weird dates from the above mentioned function. Here is what I do:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierISO8601)
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.weekday = 1
components.weekOfYear = 16
components.yearForWeekOfYear = 2016
let dateKW = calendar?.dateFromComponents(components)
```

The variable dateKW equals 24. April 2016. When I change the `weekday` to 2, I get 18. April 2016. Why is that the case? Shouldn't the first day be 17. April 2016?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Gregorian calendar, weekday units range from `1=Sunday`, `2=Monday`, ..., to `7=Saturday`. If the first weekday in your locale is *Monday* (like for example in Germany), then the 18th calendar week
in 2016 ranges from April 18 (Monday) to April 24 (Sunday).

Therefore asking for the Sunday in week #16

```
components.weekday = 1
components.weekOfYear = 16
components.yearForWeekOfYear = 2016
```

correctly returns April 24, 2016. If you need the first day of that
week then set

```
components.weekday = calendar.firstWeekday
```

or simply don't set `components.weekday` at all.

Comment: oh ok so it is more like an enum with 1=sunday ... 7=saturday alrighty, now i get it, thanks. I am getting the weekday, weekofyear and Year data from another source and i have to display them as the right days. And yes i am in germany. My solution is now that is add 1 to my weekday and fortunately it seems to return the right date for me.